# vim won't record d$ seems to ignore that command

Tags: vim

Example text:

```
aaa\bbb\ccccccc sldkfj09sju s- 349rw3 rsr9
aaa\bbb\cc sl 9r w3 rsr9
aaa\bbb\cccCccC sldkfj
aaa\bbb\ccccccccccc sld j09 sju s- 349r w3 r sr9
aaa\bbb\ccc s 09 sju s- 349r rsr9
```

I want to record deleting everything after the c folders on each line so start at beginning of first line then record this:

```
E l d $ 0 j
```

End record
When I replay it, it just jumps to the end of the next line, its not recording `d $`

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of `:reg q` *(assuming you recorded in register q, adjust otherwise)*

Comment: And ftr, I prefer using normal commands these days for that kind of operations. Following would give the same result `:%norm Eld$`

Comment: FWIW `D` is equivalent to `d$`. Does that work for you?

Comment: D works. Still curious why d$ isn't recorded, but if you submit that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Also norm (unless I'm misunderstanding how it works) is not terrible useful to me because it seems to require I know what I want to do ahead of time, with record I can do it on the fly and don't have to think about it.

Comment: Your screenshot shows it's recorded allright and if I execute your macro on my machine it does what it's supposed to do. Does it work when you start vim without any plugins? `gvim -u NONE`

Comment: I'll just leave it at that then (assume its a plugin) I should have been using D anyway.